# Any limitations on the number or size of items in a single OSS bucket

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

Is there any limit on the number and size of items in a single Forge OSS bucket?  For example, can I stick a Navisworks or Inventor or Revit model PLUS several DWG/PDF/DOC/XLS files into ONE bucket?  Will each one of those things get it's own URN if I run it through the model derivative API to get a view of each one <I assume yes, but assumptions are not good>?

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit of either file size or item number in a Forge OSS bucket, but if you're using Forge trial plan, your buckets have a storage limit of 5GB in total. See https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing

However, Forge Model Derivative API doesn't support translating office files (DOC, XLS and etc.), so you cannot use Model Derivative API to translate those formats to get views. Would advise you to keep your files on your server, and upload the necessary, supported files to Forge for translation if needed.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/